# Messed up Kicad's pcb_new view

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

I was working in my design and suddenly the view changed and I can't find the way to revert it the normal view.

Tracks do not appear solid and footprint are now not visible, any clue?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You've clicked the "show tracks in outline mode", "show pads in outline mode", and "show/hide footprints" buttons.

Click these three buttons again to turn off those modes.

[image]